# how to limit the mumber of characters in column oracle,

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I require to perform a query `select * from` which leave me the column entitled " coment " in just 56 characters , the resulting characters would have to concatenate the next row respecting the number of the sequence.
I have no idea how to do it, any suggestion is appreciated.

it is my original table:

```
 SEQUENCE COMMENT
_____________________________________________________________
|       1|COMPUTER  01777 6629378 FREE TEXT,  THIS COMMENT IS
|       2|TELEPHONE|I require to perform a query select * fro
|       3|m which leave me the column entitled " coment " in
|       4|just 56 characters        
______________________________________________________
```

This is the expected result.

```
SEQUENCE COMMENT
______________________________________________________
|      1|COMPUTER  01777 6629378 FREE TEXT,  THIS COMM
|      2|ENT IS TELEPHONE I require to perform a query 
|      3|select * from which l|eave me the column enti
|      4|tled " coment " in just 56 characters       
______________________________________________________
```

Comment: can u change the schema? in ur create command specify the varchar(limit)

Answer (score 2):

As long as the total comment length is less than 4000 characters, you can use `listagg()` to stick the pieces together into a single string (using a CTE instead of your real table; and changing your column name as both sequence and comment are reserved words):

```
with t (seq, text) as (
            select 1, 'COMPUTER  01777 6629378 FREE TEXT,  THIS COMMENT IS' from dual
  union all select 2, 'TELEPHONE I require to perform a query select * fro' from dual
  union all select 3, 'm which leave me the column entitled " coment " in ' from dual
  union all select 4, 'just 56 characters' from dual
)
select listagg(text, null) within group (order by seq)
from t;

FULL_TEXT                                                                                                                                                                                              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
COMPUTER  01777 6629378 FREE TEXT,  THIS COMMENT ISTELEPHONE I require to perform a query select * from which leave me the column entitled " coment " in just 56 characters
```

And then you can use the connect-by hierarchical syntax with `substr` to chop it back up into your desired length. I've assumed you meant 45 rather than 56 as that's the output you showed in your question:

```
with t (seq, text) as (
            select 1, 'COMPUTER  01777 6629378 FREE TEXT,  THIS COMMENT IS' from dual
  union all select 2, 'TELEPHONE I require to perform a query select * fro' from dual
  union all select 3, 'm which leave me the column entitled " coment " in ' from dual
  union all select 4, 'just 56 characters' from dual
),
y as (
  select listagg(text, null) within group (order by seq) as full_text
  from t
)
select level as seq, substr(full_text, 45 * (level - 1) + 1, 45) as text
from y
connect by level <= ceil(length(full_text) / 45);

       SEQ TEXT                                        
---------- ---------------------------------------------
         1 COMPUTER  01777 6629378 FREE TEXT,  THIS COMM
         2 ENT ISTELEPHONE I require to perform a query 
         3 select * from which leave me the column entit
         4 led " coment " in just 56 characters
```

In your real case you presumably have lots of individual comments, with some common key value; so key 1 has seq 1-4, key 2 has seq 1-3, etc. You can still use this method but you need to use a trick to stop the connect-by cycling. I've set this up with a dummy table called `comments` containing two separate values:

```
select * from comments order by fk_id, seq;

     FK_ID        SEQ TEXT                                              
---------- ---------- ---------------------------------------------------
         7          1 COMPUTER  01777 6629378 FREE TEXT,  THIS COMMENT IS
         7          2 TELEPHONE I require to perform a query select * fro
         7          3 m which leave me the column entitled " coment " in 
         7          4 just 56 characters                                 
        11          1 A second comment for a different foreign key value 
        11          2 to demonstrate combining and splitting when there a
        11          3 re multiple records
```

Then your query against that table becomes:

```
with cte as (
  select fk_id, listagg(text, null) within group (order by seq) as full_text
  from comments
  group by fk_id
)
select fk_id, level as seq, substr(full_text, 45 * (level - 1) + 1, 45) as text
from cte
connect by level <= ceil(length(full_text) / 45)
and prior fk_id = fk_id
and prior sys_guid() is not null;

     FK_ID        SEQ TEXT                                        
---------- ---------- ---------------------------------------------
         7          1 COMPUTER  01777 6629378 FREE TEXT,  THIS COMM
         7          2 ENT ISTELEPHONE I require to perform a query 
         7          3 select * from which leave me the column entit
         7          4 led " coment " in just 56 characters         
        11          1 A second comment for a different foreign key 
        11          2 value to demonstrate combining and splitting 
        11          3 when there are multiple records
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/52add/1).

Comment: I am so grateful for share your knowledge

Comment: a little doubt in the case of having a table with 10,000 records , it would be necessary to rewrite part of the  instruction union all select 10000 times for all records ?

Comment: @CesarVictorino - no, the union all in the first CTE (common table expression) is just for me to create dummy data for this demo. You would select from your own real table, not my `t` CTE.

Comment: @CesarVictorino - I've added a version that selects from a table instead, and which handles multiple comments, each of which may be split into multiple lines. Hope that is clearer.